# Is there a "clearfix" for vertical-align?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Is there a similar technique like `float` and `clearfix` but for vertical alignment.

I want to separate different elements (either inline or floating left) such that they are always aligned either to the top or bottom.

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HkTDT/) I want the red and the green to be horizontally aligned. I cannot change the CSS or the existing divs. I can only wrap `.s1` and `.s2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. If you know the class name you can do like this:

[SEE DEMO 1](http://jsbin.com/aNAKAJU/5/edit)

Here the css:

```
.s1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 20px;
}

.s2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.s3 {
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
}

/* PUT THIS IN AN EXTRA FILE OR UNDER THE ABOVE STYLE */ 

.s1 {        
    vertical-align: bottom;   
}

.s2 {        
    vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

Or if you can wrap the file you can float the div's like this:

[SEE DEMO 2](http://jsbin.com/aNAKAJU/4/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap_1"> <!-- Wrap 1 -->
    <div class="s1">
        <div class="s3">asdf</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap_2"> <!-- Wrap 2 -->
    <div class="s2">
       <div>qwer</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.s1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 20px;
}

.s2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.s3 {
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
}

/* FLOAT THE DIV */

.wrap_1 div, .wrap_2 div {

    float: left;
}
```

Let me know if solved your issue!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the class either. They don't event have a class. Only a dynamically generated ID. (That was the solution in the demo). And I tried wrapping in floats and the `baseline` vertical alignment that they have is still being considered.

Comment: But, apparently the float SHOULD do it! So there must be something else that is messing with the vertical alignment.